# Yup don't trigger the error if value typing starts with 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

Basically, I have a field need validate like this:

```
export const validationSchemaWithdraw = Yup.object().shape({
  amount: Yup.number()
    .min(1, 'The minimum amount is one')
    .typeError('The amount invalid')
    .required('The amount is required'),
});
```

If I type the amount equal to 0, error should trigger. But if value is 01 nothing happen.

How to my field trigger the error if value typing starts with 0?

Comment: On your yup schema you're defining value type as number, so '01' gets parsed to 1 and that's indeed  a valid value.

Comment: Thanks, @lbsn. How can I get what I expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're decalring the value type as `number` on yup schema, the input value will be casted to number before validation. A value like "01" will be parsed to 1, which is valid based on your validation chain.

A way to achieve the behaviour you're expecting is to add a custom `test` function to your validation chain and testing the leading zero case. This requires accessing the field's original value *as a string* (before being casted to number by yup) otherwise leading zero will be dismissed by parsing. So be sure the type of your input field is "string".

```
const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  amount: Yup.number()
    .min(1, 'The minimum amount is one')
    .typeError('The amount invalid')
    .required('The amount is required')
    .test(
      'no-leading-zero',
      'Leading zero is not allowed',
      (value, context) => {
        return context.originalValue && !context.originalValue.startsWith('0');
      }
    ),
});
```

Another option could be to change the value type to `string` on your schema and using `matches` + regex to check the string format.

Comment: Thanks again! It works. Before post this question, I tried to find Regex putting in matches, but I can't look it.

Answer (score -2):

```
amount: yup
  .number()
  .typeError('The amount invalid')
  .min(1, "The minimum amount is one")
  .required('The amount is required')
  .test( 'no-leading-zero', 'Leading zero is not allowed', 
    (value, context) => { 
      return (value && value>=1) && (context.originalValue && 
      context.originalValue.startsWith("0") ) ? false:true ; 
    } 
),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).